# How can I get items in a combobox to appear in an email?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am building an app that requests information by emailing a group once completed. I have one combobox people picker and every time the email goes through, only the final name comes through from this selection.

I am using Combobox.Selected.DisplayName- where only the final name appears. When I try Combobox.SelectedItems, I get an error and it won't work at all. I need to have all the items appear in the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of Combobox.SelectedItems is a table. If you want a single text value, you can use a function such as [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate) to aggregate them, something along the lines of

```
Concat(Combobox.SelectedItems, DisplayName, ", ")
```